# could not initialize proxy - no Session-com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToOne(optional = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PK")
  private Category parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private Set<Category> children = new HashSet<Category>();
} 

    @Test

    final Category category = new Category();
    category.setPk("4321");
    categoryRepository.save(category);

    final Category category1 = new Category();
    category1.setPk("1234");
    category1.setChildren(Collections.singleton(category));
    final Category savedCategory1 =  categoryRepository.save(category1);
```

till now everything looks okay but when i do in the next line in the `test` like following

```
final Category savedCategory2 = categoryRepository.getOne(savedCategory1.getPk());
```

i see in eclipse debug `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.`
and than the test stacktrace says

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
```

I am using default spring boot , hibernate and h2 set up and i did no configuration regarding datasource or entitymanager.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends BaseRepository<Category, String>{

}
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, PK extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, PK> {
    }
```

Comment: Wheres your query for getOne?

Comment: No query generated for getOne. I can see query till last '.save(category1);'

Comment: But you should define getOne in your repository

Comment: Its by Spring automatically. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html . These methods are provided by spring. My repository interface is empty. Spring-data-jpa does the work

Comment: No its not - its T findOne(ID primaryKey);

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

Comment: i thought you were using CrudRepository - whats Baserepository?

Comment: updated in the main description